# American Transit Visa for a Colombian

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas

Does anyone know how to apply for an American transit visa to travel through America but not to stay? I cant find anything on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A web search on "transit visa USA" turns up as the top result the official State Department [Transit Visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) page with detailed instructions; in short, you first complete a nonimmigrant visa application (the [DS-160](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/)) and then you must be interviewed by the embassy in Bogota.

Comment: https://www.google.com.co/search?q=solicitar+una+visa+de+tr%C3%A1nsito+estadounidense

Answer (score 1):

The application process and guidance is available here https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html